# Why is whois data not available for some sites?

Tags: dns, domain, domain-name, whois

I am trying to check the whois details for a site `uq.oz.au` and not able to find any data. I have tried multiple whois engines. Could someone let me know why this is the case? Shouldn't registration information for the domain be public domain?

Note I have also checked http://whois.ausregistry.com.au but this also states that there is no data. However, if I navigate to `www.uq.oz.au` I do get the University of Queensland website. Can someone explain why this is the case or if I am not searching for it correctly?

Comment: The .AU registry simply has no data for this domain in their WHOIS database!: http://gwhois.org/uq.oz.au

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.au#Historic_second-level_domains), `oz.au.` is a legacy domain that resulted from a namespace move. Data may simply not have been ported to newer systems.